# Bitmap class parameter not valid

Tags: c#, parameters, bitmap

I pass an array to a method and I use a foreach loop. The parameter I'm passing to new Bitmap() is not valid for some reason. I get the error "Parameter is not valid." The parameter is a string path (as it should be).

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

If I highlight the parameter name, this is what it shows me, which seems to be correct:

"C:\Reinstatement Image Transporter\Image Processing\NYH004402800_REINSTMT_0e2837ae.jpg"

```
public static void CompressPictures(string[] processingFiles)
        {
            string originalFileName = "";

            foreach (string file in processingFiles)
            {
                //I'm getting the error right here:
                Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(file);

                ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                Encoder myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;

                EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

                EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);

                myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 0L);
                myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

                originalFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Remove(file.Length - 1, 1));

                pic.Save(AppVars.ProcessingPolicyImagesFolder + originalFileName, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: What's the exception type being thrown? If it's a `FileNotFoundException` then the problem is pretty straightforward, but it could be the file format is not valid or supported.

Comment: ahhhhhhhh it was filenotfound!! DUH! i had a logic error. fixed it. thanks lee :)

Comment: On a side note, you're creating an unknown number if `Bitmap`s and not calling `Dispose()` on any of them.  Wrap that declaration in a `using` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Per the comments on the question above: It was a simple `FileNotFound` error.)